# border-image renders differently between Chrome and FireFox

Tags: css

I'm currently playing around with CSS3 `border-image` and noticed that there are differences in how the image is applied between Chrome and FireFox (latest versions).

I have a very basic example I'm messing around with whereby I'm applying the `border-image` to some `textarea` tags to study the different effects.

In FireFox the image is split into the sections and applied to the border sections as expected. The center is transparent as I would expect.

In Chrome it does the same with the borders but also shows the center of the image.

Is there some default setting/style which a browser applies, causing the transparency in one browser but not he other?

Is that a setting/style I can override?

#### [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/8hwnU/)

> **Edit**
>
> I suppose, seeing that the browsers simply just do that, if one can't
>   ove-write the behaviour in CSS, what could I do to ensure the images
>   are applied the same between the 2 browsers?

In case the fiddle goes stale I included the code below as well.

The HTML:

```
<textarea class="no-image">some default text</textarea>
<textarea class="stretch">some default text</textarea>
<textarea class="round">some default text</textarea>
<textarea class="repeat">some default text</textarea>​
```

The CSS:

```
textarea{
    border: 50px solid #feb515;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-image-slice: 5;
}

textarea.stretch{
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 stretch;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 stretch;
}


textarea.round{
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 round stretch;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 round stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 round stretch;
}

textarea.repeat{
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 repeat round;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 repeat round;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/groovy-border-image-slice.png) 100 repeat round;
}​
```

Comment: So weird - so this example at css tricks appears to be working properly for me, but your js fiddle isn't. I can't figure out why. http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: @quoo: that is strange. I double checked the documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-image-slice and it does say under `border-image-slice` `The ‘fill’ keyword, if present, causes the middle part of the border-image to be preserved. (By default it is discarded, i.e., treated as empty.)` I wonder if Chrome has the default mixed up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've gotten it working - I'm not sure *why* it's working though.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ysfr/2/

I think it may be that your border width needs to match up with the number specified in border-image, and I think border-image-slice may be messing things up.

Nevermind - i think it is exactly as you say - using border-image-slice causes odd behavior with the 'fill' in chrome. My example works because it is missing the offset of the border slices.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will have to check this out again at home tonight. Even when I deleted my base styles it still messed up, so I'm going to start stripping out things out of my fiddle till it pops. `+1` anyway for your fiddle as without that I would have assumed Chrome always fills the background. I will accept your answer as well as your example works and obviously I need to do the rest of the research now to determine what messes it up. Thanks again.

Comment: I also came across a site which mentions something which I think relates to it. there is no details but they are using images without centres: http://www.zurb.com/playground/awesome-overlays `What can potentially screw things up is that it takes the center section and stretches it across your entire object. So to achieve a traditional border with a transparent object, we had to cut out the center of our border image.`

Comment: Yes, I'd try, if you have the option, cutting your border image so that you don't have to use the -border-image-slice option, and that should work fine with a transparent center.